# Side effects in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, side-effects

Redux reducers should be without side-effects. But what if an action should trigger the download of a file in the browser where the content is based on the state of the store? Surely this should count as a side effect? Would something like the following be fine or should I be looking for alternative methods?

```
case 'SAVE_GRID': {
  const { json } = state
  fileDownload(json, 'data.json', 'application/json')
  return state
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you have very complex state transitions, the actual `fileDownload` should happen in an action creator, not in the reducer.  The reducer should be responsible for merging/reducing state and that is all.

action:

```
export const saveGrid = (json) => {
   return (dispatch) => {  
       fileDownload(json, 'data.json', 'application/json')
           .then(() => {
              dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_GRID', json });
           });
   }
}
```

reducer:

```
case 'SAVE_GRID': {
    return {
        ...state,
        json: action.json
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone who maybe is not already aware, you'll need a middleware like redux-thunk to be able to dispatch a function as an action like this.

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries to handle such "side" effects.

For example:

- **redux-observables**: they use RX observables under the hood.

https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html

- **redux-saga**

https://redux-saga.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

Reducers *can* drive effects, in fact they do it all the time via state changes which trigger UI rendering — arguably the application's most important effect.

Driving non-visual effects isn't as common but there are at least two solutions: redux-loop and redux-agent (which I wrote).

From the respective sites:

redux-loop:

> A port of the Elm Architecture to Redux that allows you to sequence your effects naturally and purely by returning them from your reducers. https://redux-loop.js.org/

redux-agent:

> Redux Agent extends React’s model to non-visual I/O: describe a network request, a storage operation, a websocket message, … and let the machine worry about performing it. Logic stays in the reducer, components stay lightweight, and it’s easy to see what state triggers which effect. https://redux-agent.org/

(The quotes also hint at a major difference between the two: redux-loop returns effect descriptions from the reducer, thereby changing its API and requiring a store enhancer. redux-agent works with vanilla Redux API.)

Answer (score 0):

I use the hook useReducer in lieu of redux. I'm not a fan of putting side effects in action creators - then it is unclear what the purpose of the action creator is: build an action, or run side effects?

I found a library here that fulfills my purpose:

https://github.com/Jibbedi/use-reducer-effect