# How to call a Function which is called inside Reducer, and the said Function uses the State returned by useReducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

*React v17*
I am using `useReducer`. In the **reducer function**, I need to call another function **check** for network fetch. In **check( )**, I need to access the `state`, which is returned by `useReducer`.
I am getting this error `can't access lexical declaration 'value' before initialization`.

```js
const reducerFilterdValue = (state, action) => {
    let newState ;
    switch(action.type){
      case 'increment':
        if(check()===0){
          newState={...state,counter:state.counter+1}
        }        
      break;
      default:
        newState={...state}
      break;
    }    
    return newState;
    }

const check=()=>{
   return state.counter%2
}

const [state, dispatchValue] = useReducer(
  reducerFilterdValue,
  initialFilterdValue
)
```

I have made a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-solomon-nxi4nl?file=/src/App.js) for explanation purpose.

What is the efficient way to restructure the code?
A. Should I need to call **check** from outside the `useReducer`? To do that, I think I will need to use `useEffect`.
B. I declared **check** outside of the functional component as a `let` variable, and defined it after **reducer function**, but it was not working correctly and `state` was getting changed more than once. 
C. *Some better approach which I am unable to find out?*

Comment: AFAIK you should not perform side effects inside reducer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833824/side-effects-in-redux-reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reducer should be responsible for merging/reducing state and that is all.

As someone in your question comments said, there should not be any side effectw in reducer (only state manipulations). So change the state in the reducer and check the **counter** state by using `useEffect` and ***dependency variables***.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. I will do this